# Read a GET API response to make a second POST API call within one google tag manager server side tag

Tags: javascript, api, google-tag-manager, hubspot

I'm trying to make an API call to [Hubspot Contacts API](https://legacydocs.hubspot.com/docs/methods/contacts/get_contact_by_utk) using the *hubspot user token*. I want to get the *vid* in order to then update the contact.

I am making this API call within **Google Tag Manager Server Side Container**.

Here is the initial step:

```
// retrieve APIs
const sendHttpGet = require('sendHttpGet');
const setResponseStatus = require('setResponseStatus');
const setResponseBody = require('setResponseBody');
const setResponseHeader = require('setResponseHeader');
const getAllEventData = require('getAllEventData');
const JSON = require('JSON');

//set variables
const hostname ='api.hubapi.com';
const hubid = data.userToken;
const path =['/contacts/v1/contact/',data.identificationType,'/'].join('');
const url = ['https://', hostname,path,hubid,'/profile?hapikey=',data.apiKey].join('');


//make api call

sendHttpGet (url, (statusCode,headers,body) => {
  if (statusCode >=200 && statusCode <300) {
      data.gtmOnSuccess();
      } else {
    data.gtmOnFailure();
}
  setResponseStatus(statusCode);
  setResponseBody(body);
  setResponseHeader(headers);
});
```

I want to be able to receive the API call response, which will have a property called *vid* to be able to then automatically trigger either another tag, or even within the same tag, that will update the contact using the *vid* from the first API call.

How do I do this?

Is there a way to be able to read the response within this script, map to a variable, and then map the next API call?

I'd prefer not to use 2 separate tags/scripts for this because it creates more potential breakpoints, and this simplifies the user process.

Comment: Your code doesn't make any sense - the code proceeding `//make api call` has a mis-matched set of curly braces `{` which would indicate to me that this is part of a bigger block of code. Can you ensure your code conforms to the guidelines on creating a [mre]?

Comment: @esqew, no, the amount of ```{``` makes sense and are accounted for, which one do you think is missing? there are 2 sets of ```{```, the first one, after ```(statusCode,headers,body) => {```. That is closed on the last line with ```});```. and then the ```if``` statement, which is closed.